# How do I select pseudo-elements in python with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: HTML snippet of target site]

These two elements have the exact same attributes except for the text in the pseudo-element. Is there anyway I can click on the "Practical" element. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Practical')]").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-tab']")[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo elements are not elements. So, that `::before` seems to be just a kind of text content of `div` element.
I can't give you tested answer since you didn't share a link to the page you are working on, but I can suggest.
I'd try this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-tab'][contains(.,'Practical')]")].click()
```

In case `v-tab` class name and `Practical` text content are unique enough it should work. Otherwise you will need to find nore unique locator.

Comment: Oh the mighty Prophet, I've made the cardinal sin of not waiting for the element to load...    I repent my Sins before you. It now works.

Comment: I'm not so mighty :)